# java - Does FileWriter use a buffer? (it acts like it does in my example)

Tags: java, filewriter

I am using FileWriter and I have noticed strange behavior. 
I buffer my collection myself and every x rows I use

```
 IOUtils.writelines(myList,"\n", writer );
```

It doesnt write to the file. I continue to call it with more lines and only after it is very full it writes to the file.
Does it use a buffer? I cant find it in its documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second sentence of [the `FileWriter` class overview](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) says:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding **and the default byte-buffer size** are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

*(My emphasis)*

So clearly it's buffered (unless the default byte-buffer size is zero and they're being really odd with their phrasing).

I suspect it's just using an `OutputStreamWriter` on a `FileOutputStream`. Looking at `OutputStreamWriter`:

> Each invocation of a write() method causes the encoding converter to be invoked on the given character(s). **The resulting bytes are accumulated in a buffer before being written to the underlying output stream.**

*(My emphasis)*

If you want to ensure that various buffers at various levels are flushed, to the extent you can, look at using the [`flush` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#flush%28%29).

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer.

Comment: @user: No worries, hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I also missed it in the docs and was really confused when `tail` was not showing my writes!

Answer (score 5):

I suspect it's an implementation detail, but I would expect most implementations to use a buffer, yes. You certainly shouldn't *rely* on it being unbuffered. When you flush or close the writer, it should be fine.

Note that personally I dislike using `FileWriter` as it doesn't allow you to specify the character encoding - I would typically wrap a `FileOutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it uses buffer but in some other way (low-level, buffer could be empty by default). Need to wrap it by BufferedWriter. From **BufferedWriter javadoc**:

```
"In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying
 character or byte stream.  Unless prompt output is required, it is advisable
 to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write() operations may be
  costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.  For example,

  <pre>
  PrintWriter out
    = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
  </pre>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the class `sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.CharsetSE.implWrite()`.
It uses a **ByteBuffer**.

The class StreamEncoder.CharsetSE is internally used by OutputStreamWriter which inturn is internally used by FileWriter.