# Performance: BufferedOutputStream vs FileWriter

Tags: java, performance, file-io, filewriter, disk-io

I've always used a [`FileWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to write text to a file in Java. Apparently you can also use a [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) as well. After reading both javadocs carefully, I can't seem to tell which was is faster/more efficient.

So I ask: is there a performance differential (even if minimal) between these two file I/O methods? If so, what are they and why? If not, why are they effectively the same?

Are there scenarios where one is preferred over the other? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really want to compare a `FileWriter` with a `BufferedOutputStream` to write a text file, the latter should be faster, since there a fewer I/O operations.

- In the case of `FileWriter`, each call to a write method will be persisted at once (it's unbuffered).
- In the case of a `BufferedOutputStream`, data will be written to disk, if the buffer is full (or the buffer is flushed explicity using the `flush` method).

---

But if you write text files, you should use a `Writer`; in this case we can compare a `FileWriter` with a `BufferedWriter`:

Looking at

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(...)
```

and

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(...)
```

you have the same situation regarding the number of I/O operations.

---

A `FileWriter` uses a `FileOutputStream` internally. The reason to use a `FileWriter` is that it automatically uses the default character encoding, when you write to a file (a Java internal string is encoded into UTF-8 for example). If you use an `OutputStream`, you have to encode manually in each write:

So this example for a `BufferedWriter`:

```
bw.write("Hello");
```

corresponds to that example for a `BufferedOutputStream`:

```
bos.write("Hello".getBytes(Charset.forName("utf-8")));
```

if your default encoding is `utf-8`.

An `OutputStream` deals with (raw) bytes whereas a `Writer` deals with (text) characters.

Answer (score 3):

A `FileWriter` writes *text* to *files*, while a `BufferedOutputStream` holds a buffer of arbitrary binary data in memory before writing it to another binary stream that you have to provide. They don't do the same thing at all, so comparing their performance is meaningless.

In general, buffering improves application throughput but adds latency. In the case of files, you can produce more output per second because you can transfer larger blocks to disk at once, so the overhead per byte is lower. On the other hand, while data is being buffered in memory it's not being written to disk, so it takes a longer time for any particular byte to get written to disk.

In the case of `FileWriter`, it already has an internal buffer that helps with encoding characters into bytes. Adding more buffering probably has little value.

Comment: Thanks @Joni (+1) - interesting observation, but can you *not* write text to files with `BufferedOutputStream`?!? [This article](http://www.javadb.com/write-to-file-using-bufferedoutputstream) seems to think otherwise. If that article is true, then although `FileWriter` and `BufferedOutputStream` might be intended for 2 different uses, it is *possible* (and thus the point of my question) to compare their performance when writing text to a file.

Comment: Again, very interesting stuff @Joni! According to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108043/java-does-filewriter-use-a-buffer-it-acts-like-it-does-in-my-example) it seems possible to override the internal buffer that `FileWriter` uses. I'd like to try this out, if for nothing else, for my own personal amusement. For the life of me I can't figure out how to configure an `OutputStreamWriter` and a `FileOutputStream` and inject them into a `FileWriter` constructor - any ideas? And where would I specify the new buffer size? Thanks again for all the great help so far!

Comment: As you can see in the article, in order to write text with a `BufferedOutputStream` first they have convert any text into bytes manually, by caling `getBytes`, which is inconvenient and creates an array of bytes that becomes garbage immediately

Comment: `FileWriter` is actually a subclass of `OutputStreamWriter` rigged so it can only write into a `FileOutputStream`, so if you want to customize some property you can just create an `OutputStreamWriter` connected to a `FileOutputStream`. There's no way to change the internal buffer size though. The default buffer of 8k is probably large enough for most applications.