# Is FileWriter buffered?

Tags: java, io, buffer

I would like to know whether or not FileWriter is buffered.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350248/java-difference-between-filewriter-and-bufferedwriter) SO question, it seems that it is, however in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108043/java-does-filewriter-use-a-buffer-it-acts-like-it-does-in-my-example) SO question it seems that is not (it would be a system call for each time write(..) gets called).

So, basically, reading those two Q&A, I am a little confused. Is anybody able to clearly explain it out?

**EDIT**:  Problem solved by reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) API of which I am quoting the relevant part:

> Each invocation of a write() method causes the encoding converter to
> be invoked on the given character(s). The resulting bytes are
> accumulated in a buffer before being written to the underlying output
> stream. The size of this buffer may be specified, but by default it is
> large enough for most purposes. Note that the characters passed to the
> write() methods are not buffered.
>
> For top efficiency, consider wrapping an OutputStreamWriter within a
> BufferedWriter so as to avoid frequent converter invocations. For
> example:
>
> Writer out    = new BufferedWriter(new
> OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

Since FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter, it applies to it as well.

Thanks for your time though, I am aware I asked something quite specific.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, a `FileWriter` does have internal buffering.  The buffer is a `ByteBuffer` (with default size 8192 bytes).  You can find it in the `sun.io.cs.StreamEncoder` object that `OutputStreamWriter` uses to encode characters to the chosen character set / encoding.

I looked at the Java 17 OpenJDK source code to determine this.  It is an implementation detail, and could vary depending on Java version ... and vendor.

Answer (score -1):

I would recomand to always use a BufferedWriter. It allows you to control the actual buffer size and you can guarantee that regardless of the JVM you use, IO will be buffered which brings a huge IO performance boost.

Comment: Ok but what about FileWriter is it Buffered? It has only this famous standard byte-buffer? How does it work? is the JVM who handles it?

Comment: A look in the JDK 1.7 Code showed a writeBuffer in the Writer Baseclass. So all writers have this buffer. The BufferedWriter uses a second buffer     private char cb[]; This leads to the conclusion that this hidden buffer may not be part in all JDK implementations (what about android ?)

Comment: No. The write method is overridden in OutputStreamWriter. The buffering is happening in the StreamEncoder used by OutputStreamWriter, which encodes characters to bytes.

Comment: You right, OutputStreamWriter overrides most of the write methods and circumvent the buffer in the baseclass.