# Does java.io.FileWriter buffer bytes before writing to the output stream

Tags: java, file-io, fileoutputstream, filewriter, bufferedwriter

As per java docs,

> In general, a Writer sends its output immediately to the underlying
>   character or byte stream. Unless prompt output is required, it is
>   advisable to wrap a BufferedWriter around any Writer whose write()
>   operations may be costly, such as FileWriters and OutputStreamWriters.
>   For example,
>
> PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new
>   FileWriter("foo.out")));
>
> will buffer the PrintWriter's output to the file. Without buffering,
>   each invocation of a print() method would cause characters to be
>   converted into bytes that would then be written immediately to the
>   file, which can be very inefficient.

But the following code appears as though FileWriter also buffers bytes before flushing to the output stream.

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;


 public class TestFileWriter {
 /**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter= new FileWriter("test.txt");
    File file=new File("test.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        fileWriter.write("a very long string, a very long string, a very long string, a very long string, a very long string\n");
        if(i%50 == 0)
            System.out.print("file size=" +  file.length()+",");

    }
    fileWriter.close();
    System.out.println("file size=" +  file.length());

}

}
```

Output :-

> file size=0,file size=0,file size=8192,file size=8192,file
>   size=16384,file size=24576,file size=24576,file size=32768,file
>   size=32768,file size=40960,file size=49152,file size=49152,file
>   size=57344,file size=57344,file size=65536,file size=73728,file
>   size=73728,file size=81920,file size=81920,file size=90112,file
>   size=99000

Why isn't the data being written to the file as and when it is being written ?

Comment: So i get that the OS is giving back cached information of the file size in case of open files[file.length()]. However when i break point after writing each line to the file and open the file to see if the data was written , it is still empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add

```
fileWriter.flush();
```

you can see the sizes have changed on each line.  This means buffering is occurring.

Using the debugger I traced this to the StreamEncoder which doesn't have source in the Oracle JDK but is available on line

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder.java

```
private static final int DEFAULT_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

private StreamEncoder(OutputStream out, Object lock, CharsetEncoder enc) {
    // some deleted
    if (ch == null) {
        bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(DEFAULT_BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the encoder has it's own buffer.

Note: since this is an internal class it may change in the future and it might not behave this way on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption on FileWriter seems to be correct.

References:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html

[2] [java - Does FileWriter use a buffer? (it acts like it does in my example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108043/java-does-filewriter-use-a-buffer-it-acts-like-it-does-in-my-example)

Buffering is applied at the underlying Stream Writing in Java, not at the FileWriter level.